# I have two drop down menus one below the other. When I open one drop down menu, the other one closes. How can I keep both of them open?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Using just HTML, I need both these dropdown's to be open. I really hope you can help me with this.

Comment: please post what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

`<Select>` Would be the wrong way to go for this. You'll need to use `javascript` or look for other available controls which will allow  you to keep your list visible. [This](http://www.designdim.com/2011/07/10-important-jquery-selectboxdropdown-plugins/) is one example of the many blogs which mentions such controls.

Answer (score 0):

It is a default behavior of drop-down elements.

But the <select> element have a size property where you can define the number of lines that control will be displayed. If you set a value greater than 1 the combobox will be displayed as listbox.

So you can make a JavaScript to dinamically change the size of the control to fix the viewing of the options:

```
<select size="1" onmousedown="this.size=4">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

You can read something about [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp)